# Problems with sizing a custom view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know how to size a custom view the right way. I am new in Android programming, so please be calm!

I have definied chessboard in an own xml file `board.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/BoardLayout"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TableRow>
        <de.xyz.ChessField android:id="@+id/A8" />
        <de.xyz.ChessField android:id="@+id/B8" />
....
```

Then I definied a layout, where the board is pasted in as a `fragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBoard"
        android:name="de.xyz.BoardFragment"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="00dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Now, I want to implement the `onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)` method of the `de.xyz.ChessField` to set the size of each `Field` programmaticaly.

I've tried something like that:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.i("widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec", String.valueOf(widthMeasureSpec) + ", " + String.valueOf(heightMeasureSpec));
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec / 8, heightMeasureSpec / 8);
}
```

But the `MeasureSpec` values are very strange:

```
I/widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec: 788, 788
```

or

```
I/widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec: 1073742218, -2147482860
```

Can you help me get on the wright way??
An other possiblity is to set the `LayoutParam` of each `ChessField` from outside the class, or? What is the best way??

Thank you for your help!!

P.S.: Update, using `MeasureSpec`. Why isn't there an exact height? How can I calculate it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`MeasureSpec.getSize(int measureSpec`)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#getSize(int)) to extract the hight and width from the supplied measure specification.

Then calculate height and width on the those values and use  [`View.setMeasuredDimension()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMeasuredDimension(int, int)) to set the height and width

Comment: Thanks for your help! You can take a look on my update